# Is a bit-field an object?

Tags: c, object, bit-fields

According to C11, an object is:

> **#C11 § 3: Terms, definitions, and symbols**
>   *object*: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values.

A bitfield can represent a value, so it should be an object. But, I have been told it was not the case.

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

6.2.6.1p2 says "*Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes [...]*", so it seems clear that bit-fields are objects.  Similarly, 6.2.6.1p4 refers to "*non-bit-field objects*".

3.5p1 defines the bit as the unit of data storage; a bit field is a region of bits so must be a region of data storage.  The standard distinguishes between objects and memory locations (a memory location is "*either an object of scalar type, or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width*"; 3.14p1) so an object need not have a distinct memory location.